# Download in java a webpage which makes AJAX call to load

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to get the Hotel reviews from different websites.

For Simple plain HTML Web Pages(like [TripAdvisor](http://tripadvisor.com) )  i used JSoup and did like this

```
Jsoup.connect("foo.html").get();
```

For Pages which used Javascript for Loading (like [Expedia](http://expedia.com) ) i used a Selenium WebDriver and did something like

```
driver.get("foo.html");
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

They were fine because they had links and i could use those links to crawl and get more reviews.
[image: like this]

and

[image: and like this]

The problem i face is when Downloading from pages which make AJAX calls (like [MakeMyTrip](http://makemytrip.com) ).

Here i do not know how to download the web page as the hotels list  which is there on the page and keeps coming as we scroll down. [image: sample]

Any Suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: You need a headless browser, not jsoup.

Comment: As i mentioned i used JSoup for simple web pages .  What i am asking is that how to get a page which keeps loading(using ajax call) without changing its URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using the url to which ajax call is done.

Example:

For a hotel with Id 200703241029455940 ( which comes from the [main page](http://hotelz.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/site/hotels/search?checkin=04112015&country=IN&searchText=Goa%2C%20India&roomStayQualifier=1e0e&city=GOI&area=&checkout=04132015)) we get the review from the url.

`http://hotelz.makemytrip.com/makemytrip/site/hotels/detail/responsive/hotelMmtReviews?hotelId=200703241029455940&start=10&rows=10&reviewsType=all`

A GET request to the URL returns back a JSON array of reviews and thus i could extract the hotel reviews .